# Emailing full screen of iPhone app

Tags: iphone, email, screenshot

I am developing an iPhone app for creating images using built in graphics and user defined text.

I want to be able to have my app, with built in graphics and user defined text, which can then be sent as a single image (much like a screenshot) to the email app to be emailed.

Is there a way to do this without taking a screenshot, leaving the app, going into the Photos app, selecting the screenshot, and emailing it from there?

Ultimately I would like to be able to have a button in my app that the user could tap, and the whole screen would be captured and sent directly to the mail app.

Any pointers gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 5):

To expand upon Brent's answer, the following code will grab a screenshot and save it out to the Documents directory as a PNG called screenshot.png:

```
UIWindow *screenWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenWindow.frame.size);
[screenWindow.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *screenshotPNG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshot);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error = nil;
[screenshotPNG writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screenshot.png"] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error];
```

This is a little crude, as it will leave a blank spot near the top of the screen for the title bar, and doesn't appear to grab the content from CAEAGLLayers.

Also, I don't believe you can use the standard mailto:// URL construction, followed by openURL, to send MIME-encoded attachments.  Maybe the 3.0 SDK fixes this, but I've yet to play with it.  You may need to use something like [sksmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) to send the message directly from within your application.

Comment: I bet if you looped through UIApplication's windows array and rendered them all (instead of only the keyWindow), the status bar would be drawn.

Answer (score 4):

There's also the private API `UIGetScreenImage`. It is used like so:

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();
@interface UIImage (ScreenImage)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithScreenContents;
@end

@implementation UIImage (ScreenImage)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithScreenContents
{
    CGImageRef cgScreen = UIGetScreenImage();
    if (cgScreen) {
        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgScreen];
        CGImageRelease(cgScreen);
        return result;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```

This function may be combined with `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to produce a PNG.

Comment: It still works, but only on-device (not in simulator) and Apple will definitely reject it.

Answer (score 3):

Apple is [now allowing](https://devforums.apple.com/message/149553) applications to use the;

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage(void);
```

function. Although you must remember that it returns a retained CGImageRef and you'll have to manage your memory accordingly.

They also say that, "*...a future release of iPhone OS may provide a public API equivalent of this functionality.  At such time, all applications using UIGetScreenImage() will be required to adopt the public API.*"

Answer (score 1):

[skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) is great.  If fact, it's so good, I went and cloned it and added sample project on github.  The sample GUI below adds a few bells and whistles, like a progress bar and some other goodies, but it basically maintains the core skpsmtpmessage code.

http://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work, but you can try creating a bitmap-backed graphics context, then getting your root view's Core Animation layer and calling its -renderInContext: method.  That *might* do it, but I've never tried it.

Perhaps, though, you should consider a different approach.  Is it just that you've written a bunch of custom drawing code that's visible on screen and you want to be able to draw into a file or memory buffer too?  If so, perhaps you should factor that drawing code out of your view and into a separate object that your view simply uses.  That would allow you to very easily draw it both ways.

Answer (score 0):

In OS 3.0, you can use MFMailComposeViewController:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker addAttachmentData:screenshotPNG mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"PNGfromMyApp"];
```