# Capture iPhone screen with status bar included?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screenshot

I am looking for a way to capture a screenshot on the iPhone with the top status bar included, I am currently using the following code:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size); //self.view.window.frame.size
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

The above code sucessfully takes a screenshot of the iPhone UIView but does not include the top status bar (In its place is just a blank 20px space).

Answer (score 11):

As of iOS 7, you can do this **without the use of private APIs** using

```
UIView *screenshotView = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
```

See my answer to this question:

[Moving status bar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007694/moving-status-bar-in-ios-7/19011013#19011013)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the entire contents of the screen by calling the private API `UIGetScreenImage`. See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692464/emailing-full-screen-of-iphone-app/694841#694841) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692464/emailing-full-screen-of-iphone-app) for details.

Comment: I read about this Private API function before, I am curious to know if Apple will accept the application for the iPhone for using a private API function?

Comment: Feelings vary on the use of private APIs.  Here's my take:

1) Use of private APIs is against Apple's rules and is one of the (maddeningly few) obvious ways your app can get rejected or pulled from the store; but...
2) Something as simple as a screenshot is likely to fly under the radar and not be noticed by a reviwer; and yet...
3) Apple could change that API at any point in the future, with any release, in any way, for any reason, without any warning.  I feel that any use of private APIs is setting yourself up for a support headache and creating the potential for a bad user experience.

Comment: In this particular case, I don't think there's a lot of risk if the function is access dynamically and failure accounted for: the app can just fall back to a screenshot using the standard method. The particular implementation of it in my answer uses static linking though, and that is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

As of Oct 8, 2009, the use of UIGetScreenImage got my app rejected! :( I would not advise using it.  I believe Apple is trying to clean up all the apps and make them conform to the new 3.x OS/APIs.  I'm looking for an alternative.  If anyone has any suggestions.  The video API?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using private API, why not render the entire UIWindow into the image context? It might be enough to replace `self.view` with `self.view.window` in your code.

You can also get the current window(s) as a property of the `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` instance. It's possible the status bar is on a separate window layer and maybe you'll have to render the windows in order.

Something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.window.frame.size);
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
   [window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
}
UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

At any rate, you probably don't need to resort to private API.

Comment: Alas, using the keyWindow property of UIApplication results in the same problem -- black status bar.  Apparently there's no (legal) way to capture the entire screen.

Comment: The status bar is in a separate window. You could loop through the UIApplication's `windows` property and render them onto the same image, in order.

Comment: Any way to tell which is the status bar?

Comment: You don't need to tell; just draw all of the windows. I updated my answer with some code.

Comment: (Actually, I only want the status bar, but I'll give your method a shot.)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[window.layer renderInContext...]`?

Comment: Doesn't work -- the first 20 or so rows are still `00 00 00 FF`.

Comment: (And there's only one window in the app)