# Why does hiding my status bar completely break my simple animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

**Example project:** http://cl.ly/0O2t051o081p

I want to achieve a slide-out sidebar as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007694/moving-status-bar-in-ios-7) where the status bar moves as well. I've got everything working and the sidebar slides, but as soon as I try to hide the status bar with to complete the "illusion" it stops anything from happening at all and the sidebar no longer slides out.

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.PostsView addSubview:[[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO]];

        hide = YES;
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            CGRect postsFrame = self.PostsView.frame;
            postsFrame.origin.x = self.MenuView.frame.size.width;

            self.PostsView.frame = postsFrame;
        }];
    });
}
```

Where my code basically consists of a containing view controller that contains two child view controllers (the main view controller and the sidebar view controller) built in the Storyboard.

I've also tried setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` in the plist to `NO` and calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden]` but the exact same result happens where it breaks.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that line breaks you animation, but it worked properly if I did what you said in your last paragraph, but added a layoutIfNeeded to the view before the animation (I did set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO in the info.plist).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.PostsView addSubview:[[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        hide = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
            CGRect postsFrame = self.PostsView.frame;
            postsFrame.origin.x = self.MenuView.frame.size.width;

            self.PostsView.frame = postsFrame;
        }];
    });
}
```

Also it's unnecessary to implement prefersStatusBarHidden.

Comment: Why is layoutIfNeeded required?

Comment: @DougSmith, I think it hides the status bar immediately, so it's hiding doesn't interfere with he animation. Under some conditions, one animation will cancel another animation -- that seems to be happening here.