# How do I move a child view controller, while hiding the status bar using Auto Layout instead of frames?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a view controller with multiple child view controllers in it (set up using Storyboards), and I move the one on top to the right (with the status bar as well) to display the underlying sidebar view controller.

This works perfectly with frames, as shown below:

```
- (void)displaySidebar {
    self.fullScreenSnapshotOverlay = [self takeFullScreenSnapshot];
    [self.postsView addSubview:self.fullScreenSnapshotOverlay];

    [self hideStatusBar];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        CGRect newFrame = self.postsView.frame;
        newFrame.origin.x += 200.0;

        self.postsView.frame = newFrame;
    }];
}
```

(`hideStatusBar` simply called the UIApplication method and layoutIfNeeded.)

Giving me this (perfect) result:

[image]

However, if in the Storyboard I go to the container view controller and make a constraint from its leading space to the left of the view controller it's embedded in, and then adjust that constant, it really messes up the navigation bar, I assume due to hiding the status bar and taking a screenshot. I'm using this code:

```
- (void)displaySidebar {
    self.fullScreenSnapshotOverlay = [self takeFullScreenSnapshot];
    [self.postsViewController.view addSubview:self.fullScreenSnapshotOverlay];

    [self hideStatusBar];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.postsViewControllerDistanceFromLeftSideConstraint.constant = 270.0;

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Giving me this messed up result:

[image]

Now I know the simple thing to do would be to just continue with frames, but I'd like to learn how do it properly with Auto Layout. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer to see how it differs from what you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how what I did is any different from what you're doing. I modified the code I posted to your other question ([Why does hiding my status bar completely break my simple animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551749/why-does-hiding-my-status-bar-completely-break-my-simple-animation/20555140#20555140)) to what's below, and it worked fine.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(displaySidebar) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)displaySidebar {
    self.snapshotView = [self takeSnapshot];
    [self.PostsView addSubview:self.snapshotView];
    [self hideStatusBar];
    self.leftCon.constant = 270;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}


-(void)moveOutMenu { // called from a button in the menu controller
    self.leftCon.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        [self.snapshotView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
    }];
}

-(UIView *)takeSnapshot {
    UIView *v = [[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
    return v;
}

-(void)hideStatusBar {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

What are all the constraints you have on the container view that you're moving? Maybe there's something different there (I have top, leading, bottom and width constraints on mine -- leftCon is the outlet to the leading constraint).

Comment: I tried a similar code sample as well, and it still doesn't work: http://cl.ly/1721281L3Z1k

Comment: @Aloha64, yours doesn't work because you have a constraint to the top layout guide instead of the top of the view (for the container view). Delete that constraint, then go to the Editor menu and choose Pin --> "Top Space To Superview"