# ios slide status bar with SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is a fairly specific question so I'm not expecting a ton of responses, but it's worth a shot. I'm using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) for my app and I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck implementing a [sliding status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007694/moving-status-bar-in-ios-7/19011013#19011013) bar while using SWRevealViewController. I've had some luck but ran into issues when pushing new views.

If so, would you mind sharing how you were able to accomplish this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to tackle the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above solution is not complete and does not work for all cases. Here the complete and robust solution.

**1. Define local Boolean** to set true when menu is open and false when menu is closed. `@property (nonatomic, readwrite) BOOL isMenuOpen;`. In my example, I synthesized it.

**2. Detect when menu is open and when it is closed.**

```
-(void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    switch (position) {
        case FrontViewPositionLeftSideMostRemoved:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionLeftSideMostRemoved");
            break;

        case FrontViewPositionLeftSideMost:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionLeftSideMost");
            break;

        case FrontViewPositionLeftSide:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionLeftSide");
            break;

        case FrontViewPositionLeft:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionLeft");
            isMenuOpen = false;
            break;

        case FrontViewPositionRight:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionRight");
            isMenuOpen = true;
            break;

        case FrontViewPositionRightMost:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionRightMost");
            break;

        case FrontViewPositionRightMostRemoved:
            NSLog(@"RevealView: FrontViewPositionRightMostRemoved");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**3. Animate status bar** similar to above answer, but more robust if e.g. menu is not closed entirely and snaps back open.

```
#pragma mark - SWRevealViewControllerDelegate

- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureMovedToLocation:(CGFloat)location progress:(CGFloat)progress overProgress:(CGFloat)overProgress {
    UIView *statusBarView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:[@[@"status", @"Bar"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];

    statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(progress * self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, 0.0f);
}

- (void) revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController animateToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position {

    NSLog(@"animateToPosition: %ld", (long)position);

    UIView *statusBarView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:[@[@"status", @"Bar"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];


    if (position == FrontViewPositionRight) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, 0.0f);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            isMenuOpen = true;
        }];
    } else if (FrontViewPositionLeft) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0.0f);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            isMenuOpen = false;
        }];
    }
}
```

**4. Detect device rotation** using notification. This is needed as the status bar is re-initialized when e.g. coming back from landscape to portrait. Put this in `viewDidLoad`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

**5. Handle device orientation change** back to portrait (to be completed for upside-down).

```
- (void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self updateOrientationForStatusBar];
}

- (void)updateOrientationForStatusBar
{
    switch ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        {
            UIView *statusBarView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:[@[@"status", @"Bar"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];

            if (isMenuOpen) {
                statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, 0.0f);
            } else {
                statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0.0f);
            }

        }
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:
        case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make use of the `RevealControllerdelegate` methods in order to animate or update the x position of it.  Something like this:

Update Status Bar on manual sliding:

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController panGestureMovedToLocation:(CGFloat)location progress:(CGFloat)progress overProgress:(CGFloat)overProgress {
    NSLog(@"6progress: %f", progress);

    UIView *statusBarView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:[@[@"status", @"Bar"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];

    statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(progress * self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, 0.0f);

}
```

Update Status Bar on toggle action:

```
- (void) revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController animateToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position {

NSLog(@"animateToPosition: %ld", (long)position);

UIView *statusBarView = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKey:[@[@"status", @"Bar"] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];


if (!isDrawerOpen) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth, 0.0f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        isDrawerOpen = true;
    }];

} else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        statusBarView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0.0f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        isDrawerOpen = false;
    }];

  }
}
```