# How to get status bar images in iPhone APP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to get status bar images without UIGetScreenImage() because this method is Private API.

Apple recommend

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1703.html

as a alternate solution, but this way can't get status bar images.

Would like to know how to get status bar images?

Comment: Why do you want status bar images? If you really want to, you could just press Home and Lock, that will take a full screenshot. Then you can remove the bottom part.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible without using the Private API.

Referencing this duplicate: [Emailing full screen of iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692464/emailing-full-screen-of-iphone-app/694841#694841)

```
CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();
@interface UIImage (ScreenImage)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithScreenContents;
@end

@implementation UIImage (ScreenImage)
+ (UIImage *)imageWithScreenContents
{
    CGImageRef cgScreen = UIGetScreenImage();
    if (cgScreen) {
        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgScreen];
        CGImageRelease(cgScreen);
        return result;
    }
    return nil;
}
@end
```